# Date iCal and Organic Groups: Make an iCal feed (subscription) accessible for a private group outside of Drupal?

Tags: 7, views, users, feeds, organic-groups

I'm making a calendar iCal feed for a private group using [Date iCal](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_ical), [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) and Views. The group events created are private, for that group only, causing a dilemma.

It all works great while I'm logged in and testing the feed via my web browser (where I'm logged in at). When I access the feed in another browser or calendar app, the feed is still valid and "intentionally left blank" due to great Drupal security built in...

How do I get around that? The ideal solution is to enable basic HTTP authentication and login that way via the calendar app. The calendar app offers an option for entering user/pass to access a link via basic authentication.

Otherwise, the site I'm working on won't contain very sensitive info and I'd be happy generating an obscure view path to share internally, and a view that somehow bypasses the OG roles (I know, that's evil!).

Any ideas on how to proceed? I appreciate any feedback in advance! :D

Comment: So far I've experimented with the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services), [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) and [Services Basic Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_basic_auth) modules: all great components for accessing private data for specific users utilizing basic HTTP authentication. While I might be able to deliver data in various formats like JSON with new displays, I'm unable to deliver the rendered output from a pre-existing display (e.g. iCal feed from Date iCal view display). I'm still digging...

Comment: I guess I could create a custom services module, powered by services module, that renders out the iCal view and delivers it. I'll look into it.

Comment: I created a custom services module today that attempts to integrate Services Basic Authentication and acting as a middle man, loading the Date iCal view then delivering it. It works... but behaves the exact same way as my original inquiry (yuck). :( You can view the module code [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2424433#comment-9622635). Any thoughts?